# How to display Top and bottom view as constant in a layout - android

Tags: android

i've one layout with one top view ,bottom view and scrollview.

Scrollview contains edittext. when edit text got focus, bottomview also scroll to up . how to avoid this.

I've tried in manifest file android:windowSoftInputMode as

```
adjustResize

adjustPan
```

But still btm layout scroll , or top layout move up.

my sample layout is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#123456" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/btmView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#123456" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <View

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                 />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want top layout and bottom layout must be constants.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   android:layout_below="@+id/topView"
   android:layout_above="@+id/btmView"
```

in ScrollView Like This

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/topView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#123456" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/btmView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#123456" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 
             android:layout_below="@+id/topView"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btmView"
           >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <View

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1000dp"
                     />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```